# Can't reuse newly populated links using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I've written a script in `node.js` in combination with `puppeteer` to parse the `links` to all the titles of posts from a webpage and navigate using those `links` to its inner page to scrape the title.

I could have scraped the titles from it's landing page but my intention is to navigate using those newly populated links and parse the title from the target page. When I execute my script, It scrapes the first title then throws an error. How can I make it successful following the logic I tried to apply.

[Link to the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping)

[Link to one of such target pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52964781/how-to-search-content-related-to-keyword-in-an-website)

This is my script so far:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&pageSize=50");
    page.waitForSelector(".summary");
    const sections = await page.$$(".summary");

    for (const section of sections) {
        const itemName = await section.$eval(".question-hyperlink", item => item.href);

        (async function main() {
            await page.goto(itemName);
            page.waitForSelector(".summary");
            const titles = await page.$$("#question-header");

            for (const title of titles) {
                const itmName = await title.$eval("#question-header .question-hyperlink", itm => itm.innerText);
                console.log(itmName);
            }
        })();
    }
    browser.close();
})();
```

What I can see in the console:

```
(node:1992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation.
    at rewriteError (c:\Users\WCS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\ExecutionContext.js:144:15)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:1992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1992) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

How to search content related to keyword in an website?

(node:1992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for selector ".summary" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
    at new WaitTask (c:\Users\WCS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:862:28)
    at Frame._waitForSelectorOrXPath (c:\Users\WCS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:753:12)
    at Frame.waitForSelector (c:\Users\WCS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\FrameManager.js:711:17)
    at Page.waitForSelector (c:\Users\WCS\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Page.js:1043:29)
    at main (c:\Users\WCS\scrape.js:15:18)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
(node:1992) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

You can see that I got a result within the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches to solving your issue:

**First**: create an array of URLs to traverse then reuse the `page` to visit them.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&pageSize=50", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector(".summary");
    const urls = await page.$$eval(".question-hyperlink", items => items.map(item => item.href));
    console.log(urls);

    for (let url of urls) 
    {
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitForSelector("#question-header");
        let title = await page.$eval("#question-header a", item => item.textContent);
        console.log(title);
    }

    await browser.close();
})();
```

**Second**: As Romain suggested create another page and use it to iterate over pages.

Here's a copy of your script with approach 2 implemented and also a couple other issues corrected (missing `await` operators, incorrect selector on the question page)

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const newPage = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&pageSize=50", {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.waitForSelector(".summary");
    const sections = await page.$$(".summary");

    for (const section of sections) {
        let itemURL = await section.$eval(".question-hyperlink", item => item.href);

        await newPage.goto(itemURL);
        await newPage.waitForSelector("#question-header"); // <-- was ".summary"
        let titles = await newPage.$$("#question-header");

        for (let title of titles) {
            let itmName = await title.$eval("#question-header .question-hyperlink", itm => itm.innerText);
            console.log(itmName);
        }
    }
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Wish I could give you thousand upvotes @Vaviloff!! It perfectly did the doing.

Comment: Glad I could help, but Romain suggested the same thing too. Also, see edit for approach one which is a bit more optimized I think.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't replayed the scenario, but your two errors are coming from:

- Two missing `await` in front of `page.waitForSelector(".summary");`
- You navigate away from your context with the `page.goto()` inside your for loop, then try to evaluate something on your `section` object which is not part of the DOM anymore.

To resolve the first one, simply add the two missings `await`.

To resolve the second one, open up a new page with `let newPage = await browser.newPage()` and `newPage.goto('whereveryouwanttogo.com')`. This way, you don't break your original`page` and can still do your `section` stuff.

Comment: What you have mentioned is why I get those errors but how come it leads me to the solution @Romain? Thanks anyways.

Comment: It's the worst ever solution i can think of @Romain. If I cope with your logic I may end up opening as many new pages as the links. Thanks.

Comment: So ? Close the pages when you are done scraping them.

Comment: @asmitu Just create `newPage` outside of `for` loop, together with `page` and later reuse it as many times as necessary.